# Run command on GPS fix

Tags: gpsd

I have `GPSD` running on a Linux system (specifically `SkyTraq Venus 6` on a `Raspberry Pi 3`, but that shouldn't matter). Is there a way to trigger a command when the GPS first acquires or loses the 3D fix, almost like the scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d` and `/etc/network/if-down.d`?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution:

**Step 1**: With `GPSD` running, `gpspipe -w` outputs `JSON` data, documented [here](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/gpsd_json.html). The `TPV` class has a `mode` value, which can take one of these values:

- 0=unknown mode
- 1=no fix
- 2=2D fix
- 3=3D fix

**Step 2**: Write a little program called `gpsfix.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import errno
import json

modes = {
  0: 'unknown',
  1: 'nofix',
  2: '2D',
  3: '3D',
}

try:
  while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line: break # EOF

    sentence = json.loads(line)
    if sentence['class'] == 'TPV':
      sys.stdout.write(modes[sentence['mode']] + '\n')
      sys.stdout.flush()
except IOError as e:
  if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:
    pass
  else:
    raise e
```

For every `TPV` sentence, `gpspipe -w | ./gpsfix.py` will print the mode.

**Step 3**: Use `grep 3D -m 1` to wait for the first fix, and then quit (which sends `SIGPIPE` to all other processes in the pipe).

`gpspipe -w | ./gpsfix.py | grep 3D -m 1` will print `3D` on the first fix.

**Step 4**: Put in in a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Wait for first 3D fix
gpspipe -w | ./gpsfix.py | grep 3D -m 1

# Do something nice
cowsay "TARGET LOCATED"
```

And run it:

```
$ ./act_on_gps_fix.sh

3D
 ________________
< TARGET LOCATED >
 ----------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Comment: I think you went a step too far. There is no need to use another pipe and grep the output, when you can simply exit your script if you find that `sentence['mode'] == 3`. So `if sentence['class'] == 'TPV' and sentence['mode'] == 3: sys.exit(0)` shoudl do it.

Comment: Indeed! If I recall correctly, I piped the output of `gpsfix.py` to other things, too. Maybe a log file.